# connecting 1-Wire device powers off wemo d1 mini

Tags: arduino, 1-wire

I have a wemos D1 Mini (an ESP8266 chip) which I am trying to connect to a 1-Wire temperature sensor.

[image]

However when I plug it in the 5v or ground it seems to power off the device, this happens with or without the data pin connected (lights stop blinking, usb disconnects). When I try this on an uno everything works fine.

**I'm guessing somehow the 1-Wire is drawing too much power but I'm not too sure how to fix it (or if it is fixable)** as I'm not too experienced with electronics.

I have tried with bigger and smaller pull up resistors (1k, 20K) but neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was doing something really stupid, I had the ground and 5V round the wrong way.